# Error reading Esri Grid format using GeoServer?

Tags: raster, geoserver, esri-grid-format

Using GDAL I can extract information from an [ArcGRID raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000000w000000), just by giving the name of the grid folder:

```
gdalinfo -stats grid_folder
```

All the statistics show up. I have tried with many arcGRID files and works fine.

However, if I want to add that ArcGRID raster to Geoserver as a new datastore, I cannot add it to it. First, I cannot specify the grid folder as the repository for the datastore, but secondly, if I try adding any of the .adf files, either it works. Geoserver displays the following message:

```
Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: Unable to parse the header for the provided input
```

In addition, this the output of gdalinfo printed in a text file:

[image: gdalinfo -stats gebco]

(I have omitted all the output rows from the attribute table)

I thought Geoserver used GDAL for compability. Any idea, apart from using gdal_translate to convert the GRID files into tiff or any other?

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific extension for GDAL sources in GeoServer.

Please check the links below:

- http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html
- http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/install_run/imageio_ext_install.html
- http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adding_data/data_format.html

Comment: I have those GDAL extensions already in my Geoserver 2.4.2

Comment: Can you paste the output of the gdalinfo here?
It might be that the CRS or the georeferencing is missing.